# Rails joins and includes multiple tables

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following models:

```
class Vendor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :warehouse_ingredients
  has_many :warehouse_ingredient_logs
end


class WarehouseIngredient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :vendor
end

class WarehouseIngredientLog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :vendor
end
```

I want all the records from WarehouseIngredient & WarehouseIngredientLog tables where vendor_id = 1?

Edit 1

Here is the data from WarehouseIngredient

```
# id, warehouse_id, ingredient_id, vendor_id, quantity, cost, lot_number, created_at, updated_at
'1', '1', '1', '1', '48.00000000', '0.84800000', 'ip201803241', '2018-03-24 14:07:17', '2018-03-24 14:07:17'
'2', '1', '2', '1', '13.00000000', '1.39300000', 'ip201803241', '2018-03-24 14:07:17', '2018-03-24 14:07:17'
'3', '1', '3', '1', '43.00000000', '1.50200000', 'ip201803241', '2018-03-24 14:07:17', '2018-03-24 14:07:17'
'4', '1', '4', '1', '12.00000000', '0.36100000', 'ip201803241', '2018-03-24 14:07:17', '2018-03-24 14:07:17'
'25', '1', '1', '1', '35.00000000', '1.00000000', 'ip2018032510', '2018-03-25 08:11:17', '2018-03-25 08:11:17'
'26', '1', '2', '1', '41.00000000', '1.00000000', 'ip2018032510', '2018-03-25 08:11:17', '2018-03-25 08:11:17'
'27', '1', '3', '1', '13.00000000', '1.00000000', 'ip2018032510', '2018-03-25 08:11:17', '2018-03-25 08:11:17'
'28', '1', '4', '1', '50.00000000', '1.00000000', 'ip2018032510', '2018-03-25 08:11:17', '2018-03-25 08:11:17'
```

Entries in this table will increase or decrease as the ingredients are removed (row removed ) or added (new row added). Also it is possible that one ingredient can have multiple entries at the same time with different lot_numbers.

from WarehouseIngredientLog

```
# id, warehouse_id, ingredient_id, vendor_id, bill_id, quantity, cost, lot_number, transaction_type, created_by_id, updated_by_id, created_at, updated_at
'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '48.00000000', '0.84800000', 'ip201803241', '0', '1', '1', '2018-03-24 14:07:17', '2018-03-24 14:07:17'
'2', '1', '2', '1', '1', '13.00000000', '1.39300000', 'ip201803241', '0', '1', '1', '2018-03-24 14:07:17', '2018-03-24 14:07:17'
'3', '1', '3', '1', '1', '43.00000000', '1.50200000', 'ip201803241', '0', '1', '1', '2018-03-24 14:07:17', '2018-03-24 14:07:17'
'4', '1', '4', '1', '1', '12.00000000', '0.36100000', 'ip201803241', '0', '1', '1', '2018-03-24 14:07:17', '2018-03-24 14:07:17'
'25', '1', '1', '1', '10', '35.00000000', '1.00000000', 'ip2018032510', NULL, '1', '1', '2018-03-25 08:11:17', '2018-03-25 08:11:17'
'26', '1', '2', '1', '10', '41.00000000', '1.00000000', 'ip2018032510', NULL, '1', '1', '2018-03-25 08:11:17', '2018-03-25 08:11:17'
'27', '1', '3', '1', '10', '13.00000000', '1.00000000', 'ip2018032510', NULL, '1', '1', '2018-03-25 08:11:17', '2018-03-25 08:11:17'
'28', '1', '4', '1', '10', '50.00000000', '1.00000000', 'ip2018032510', NULL, '1', '1', '2018-03-25 08:11:17', '2018-03-25 08:11:17'
```

Entries in this table will contain all records of data, so any change in the previous table values will be logged here.

My desired result is to get data for Vendor 1 ingredient 1, where transaction_type = 0;

Comment: your question is unclear what you are trying to achieve here. if you are looking for `WarehouseIngredient & WarehouseIngredientLog` from the `vendor` it is pretty straightforward. no need of using `join` or `includes` rails association is enough to do it. so please add your expected result to question and explain what all you tried so far.

Comment: @VishalTajPM is right.
if you need 1 vendor with WI x WILog, then use joins.
like joins(: warehouse_ingredients, :warehouse_ingredient_logs)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not need anything from Vendor. What I need is all WI and their related data from WIL. So need to join these two but there is not direct association between these two models.